# How to use external Javascript file in Android WebView HTML page?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to launch an html page as a WebView, with some attached Javascript. I want the script to execute on submission of an html form.

The relevant code is below. I am storing the html data as a string in order to pass it to loadDataWithBaseUrl. The baseurl I give is the assets folder, as created by Android Studio (app --> assets). javascript.js is a direct child of that directory.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String htmlString =

                    "<html>\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "    <script src=\"file:///android_asset/javascript.js/\" " +
                    "type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n" +
                    "</head>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<form id=\"form\" onsubmit=\"tokenize(form)\">\n" +
                    "    <div>\n" +
                    "        <label>First Name</label>\n" +
                    "        <input type=\"text\" first-
                             name=\"first_name\">\n" +
                   ....
                   ....
                    "\n" +
                    "    <div id=\"tokenize\">\n" +
                    "        <button type=\"submit\">Tokenize!</button>\n" +
                    "    </div>\n" +
                    "</form>\n" +
                    "<script>\n" +
                    "function tokenize(form_id) {\n" +
                    ....
                    "           }</script>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>\n";

    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
            htmlString,
            "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    setContentView(webview);
```

I expect the "script src=..." in my html to load in the javascript file so that I can access its functions.

When I run the program in the Android emulator, however, logcat gives the error "Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/javascript.js/". Trying to submit the html form, of course, crashes the app.

What am I doing wrong here? I can't figure out why it is unable to load the javascript file. I've been googling and scraping stackoverflow for hours, and I see some similar issues but no solutions that seem to apply here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `src=\"javascript.js\" `.

Comment: `with some attached Javascript`. ? Attached?